# Allow maximal 1 build in queue for same Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can we configure jenkins in a way that it doesnot rebuild the modules which it already build in previous run for same pipeline

I found Throttle Concurrent Builds in jenkins but that is applied to node specific. my requirement is not node specific.

Answer (score 0):

There should also be a 'Do not allow concurrent builds' option in the pipeline configuration that might help for regular pipelines.

I am using [Lockable Resources](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/) as a workaround for tests, that can influence each other via network or are tested with multibranch pipelines (jenkins recognizes concurrent build only within same branch).
So I create a lockable resource with module-specific label, that is locked in the pipeline. So if the same pipeline is started again, it has to wait for the lock to be freed by the first.